# Assert for void methods junit testing

Tags: java, junit, assert, void

I am trying to write testcase for below mentioned  void method .Can somebody help me with correct assert statement to be used for testing this method.

```
   public void contextInitialized(com.servlet22.ServletContextEvent sce)
{       
    try {
        // if 'corePoolSize' is 0 then it means no idle thread will be there. Only one active job will be functional.
        int corePoolSize = Integer.parseInt(sce.getServletContext().getInitParameter(Constants.WOJOB_JOB_THREAD_NUMBER));
        scheduler = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize);
        //context created
        String woPropFile = EnvironmentBasedConfigurationHandler.getInstance().getValue(sce.getServletContext().getInitParameter(Constants.WO_CONFIGURATION_FILE));
        Properties woProp = new Properties();
        InputStream is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(woPropFile);
        woProp.load(is);
        String ftpConfigFile = EnvironmentBasedConfigurationHandler.getInstance().getValue(sce.getServletContext().getInitParameter(Constants.FTP_CONFIGURATION_FILE));
        String dbConfigFile = EnvironmentBasedConfigurationHandler.getInstance().getValue(sce.getServletContext().getInitParameter(Constants.DB_CONFIGURATION_FILE));
        WOJob.init(ftpConfigFile, dbConfigFile, woProp);
        WOJob woJob = WOJob.getInstance(scheduler);
        scheduler.schedule(woJob, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        logger.log("WOJobInitializerListener.contextInitialized()", "Configuration file path fetched from web.xml and WOJob has initialized and started");

    } catch (Throwable th) {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        th.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
        logger.log("WOJob.run()", "Unable to initialize WOJob Thread due to : " + sw.toString());
    }        
}
```

Junit test for this i have written below -

```
public class WOJobInitializerListenertest {
    ServletContext servletCtx = Mockito.mock(ServletContext.class);
    ServletContextEvent sce = Mockito.mock(ServletContextEvent.class);
    @Test
    public void test() {
         Mockito.when(Integer.parseInt(sce.getServletContext().getInitParameter(Constants.WOJOB_JOB_THREAD_NUMBER))).thenReturn(0); 
         Mockito.when(EnvironmentBasedConfigurationHandler.getInstance().getValue(sce.getServletContext().getInitParameter(Constants.WO_CONFIGURATION_FILE))).thenReturn("wo.properties");  
         Mockito.when(EnvironmentBasedConfigurationHandler.getInstance().getValue(sce.getServletContext().getInitParameter(Constants.FTP_CONFIGURATION_FILE))).thenReturn("ftp.config");    

         Mockito.when(EnvironmentBasedConfigurationHandler.getInstance().getValue(sce.getServletContext().getInitParameter(Constants.DB_CONFIGURATION_FILE))).thenReturn("db.config");  
         WOJobInitializerListener el = new WOJobInitializerListener();
        
        /*what assert can be used?*/
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about verifying that some functions are called?

Demo:

```java
@Mock
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor scheduler;


/*what assert can be used?*/
verify(scheduler).schedule(anyObject(), 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```